# Android anti-crack, is it worth it anyway?

Tags: android, security

I'm making my first Android app, and it will be a paid (1$) app targeting API8 (Android 2.2).

Right now I see 2 options for protecting my app from sharing:

- Using Android license checking : The problem is that the device must have an internet connection, and that as I've read on the net, the license caching is buggy. And, the biggest draw back is that it can be cracked anyway by an average cracker... Also, I don't want to penalise honest users by slowing down the app startup or by exiging an internet connection.
- Using ProGuard, and activating the legacy anti-copy option when publishing the app : Is this unsecure to the point that even a newbie would be able to copy / share my app ?

Also, I don't wont to spend a lot of time on the security of my app, so please don't suggest solutions that are hard to implement / time consuming.

For now I'm more for the second option. Please help me decide, and tell me if I'm wrong in what I've said.

[UPDATE]
One more question : Does the Android LVL add more encryption to the APK and make it more difficult to share ? Or is it only used to check the license online ? Is it safe to not use it at all and only use Proguard and the legacy anti-copy option when uploaded ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is simple! Do not waste your time in adding protection...it will be cracked the minute it gets uploaded and WILL be pirated very easily!

Use proguard as your best defence for the app to obfuscate the names of classes into single-lettering scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just one more question, does the Android LVL add more encryption to the APK and make it more difficult to share ? Or is it only used to check the license online ? Is it safe to not use it at all and only use Proguard and the legacy anti-copy option when uploaded ?